# To align the two buttons below

Tags: php, html, css

I am using a div and I've setup kind of the start of the login system but I can't for some reason get the buttons to go below. Screenshot shows issue:

[image]

I used the thing on CSS at the very bottom. I don't know if any of the other CSS would help.

Also as this is soon going to be a  login system with database I'm wondering if there is a website that anyone found handy when making theirs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/header.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/site.css">
</head>
<body>



<?php include '../header.html'; ?>
    <div class="body-container">
        <div class="menu">
            <div class="login-container" style="">
                <h1 style="padding-bottom: 10px;">Username</h1>
                <input type="username" style="color: black; height: 50px; font-size:14pt;" name="user">
                <h1>Password</h1>
                <input type="Password" style="color: black; height: 50px; font-size:14pt; margin-top: 5%; " name="user">
                <button>test</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>



</body>


</html>
```

```
* {
     margin: 0;
     font-family: Arial;
     color: white;
}
 body {
     background-image: url(../img/Background-Blurred.jpg);
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-attachment: fixed;
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: center;
     overflow-: hidden;
     overflow: hidden;
}
 .navbar {
     list-style-type: none;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     width: 100%;
     overflow: hidden;
     background-color: darkgrey;
     height: 46px;
     border-bottom: 0.05px solid black;
}
 li {
     float: left;
}
 li a {
     display: block;
     color: white;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 14px 16px;
     text-decoration: none;
}
 a:hover:not(.active) {
     background-color: #a0a0a0;
     border-bottom: 0.05px solid black;
     border: 0.05px solid black;
     box-shadow: 0 12px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24), 0 17px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}
/*The body in the center of website */
 .body-container {
     height: 100%;
     width: 50%;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     position: relative;
}
 .menu {
     padding: 20px;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     width: auto;
     height: 100rem;
     background-color: darkgrey;
     text-decoration-color: black;
}
 .body-container .menu .title {
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     text-align: center;
}
 .body-container .body-text {
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     text-align: center;
     padding-top: 2.5%;
     text-align: left;
}
 .body-text {
     font-size: 25px;
}
 .announcement {
     height: 100px;
     padding: 5px;
     width: auto;
     background-color: midnightblue;
     text-align: center;
     margin-top: 20px;
     vertical-align: middle;
     border-radius: 25px;
}
 .announcement-text {
     padding-top: 10px;
}

.body-container .menu .login-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 40%;
    size: 50px;

}
```

Comment: give the button position:absolute;

Comment: To Password input box. Set display:block;

Comment: @godfather do you know how I can fix this. https://i.imgur.com/xuU8XOr.png basically its fine when its on normal resolution but when I goto mobile it makes the box move to the right and not center.```.body-container .menu .login-container button {
     position:absolute; 
     color: black; 
     margin-top: 20%; 
     margin-left: 75%; 
     width: 50px; 
     height: 50px;
}``` also how can i make it so the boxs are all at the center. i

Comment: yeah usualy we start in diffrent way with display and positioning

Comment: you talking about the whole content to be centered or the buttons

Comment: @godfather whole content.

Comment: ok ill copy it to my vscode and try to make it responsive

Comment: sorry i had something to do im back so i can change your css to make better  if you allow me just an example?

Comment: @StuartLittle plz check my answer if you like it and thats what you want plz accept it i tried my best  if theres something else tell me  thank you

Comment: @StuartLittle did you fix your problem? if this answer i posted doesnt help let me change it to the last answer position:absolute the way i solved it before so you can accept the answer plz

Answer (score 2):

Before haphazardly throwing patches and hacks to "fix" your form, we should back up and start with a valid, syntactically correct form. I took your form markup and ironed out the bugs as well as making some enhancements and accessibility improvements.

- Surround the `form` elements in a `<form></form>`
- There is no `type="Username"` (changed to `type="text"`)
- `type="Password"` should be `type="password"`
- Use `label`s instead of `h1`s, and associate them with your form inputs using the `for` attribute. The value of the `for` attribute is an `id` that is added to the `input` the label is pointing to. You'll know it's working correctly when clicking the `label` focuses your cursor in the `input`
- Separate `CSS` from `HTML` for clarity/readability and for the ability to reuse styles
- Use `flexbox`for layout (I'm using a columnar direction for this form to stack children)

### Result

[image]

### Demo

```css
.login-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.login-container input {
  font-size: 14pt;
  padding: .25em .5em;
  color: black;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}

.login-container .actions {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.login-container [type="submit"] {
  margin-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<form action="/login" method="post" class="login-container">
  <label for="username">Username</label>
  <input id="username" type="text">
  <label for="password">Password</label>
  <input id="password" type="password">
  <div class="actions">
    <a href="#">Forgot password?</a>
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jk18693q/5/)

Answer (score 1):

The real problem is you don't have any block level elements encapsulating your "rows".  The only reason the other inputs are on there own line is the heading tags force them there.

So the best thing to do is this (IMO)

```
<div class="login-container" style="">
        <div class="row" >
            <h1 style="padding-bottom: 10px;">Username</h1>
            <input type="username" style="color: black; height: 50px; font-size:14pt;" name="user">
        </div>
        <div class="row" >
            <h1>Password</h1>
            <input type="Password" style="color: black; height: 50px; font-size:14pt; margin-top: 5%; " name="user">
        </div>
        <div class="row" >
            <button>test</button>
        </div>
   </div>
```

Then it's a simple matter of doing `text-align:center` on the last "row".

Personally I would use a Label field instead of a Heading, that way you can use the `for="{inputId}` to make the labels clickable like they should be.  Guess I am just "old school" when it comes to forms.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want the button to appear below the password field right?

Usually I divide my forms into rows using divs, since by default they are display: block and full width. Something like this:

```
<div>
  <input type="Password" style="color: black; height: 50px; font-size:14pt; margin-top: 5%; " name="user">
<div>
<div class="login-btn-group">
   <button>test</button>
<div>
```

Then you can target that div and align the buttons however you want

```
.login-btn-group {
    text-align: right;
}
```

You could also use flex box or floats but this is simple. Plus, once you add labels (which you should) you can include those in the divs to keep them together like individual components

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for what i can see, the easiest way is to, on css:

```
button{
  position: relative;
  top: 6rem; // this will make your button get to any position you want following the (top, left, right, bottom) change the number to whatever suits you.
}
```

the other thing, if you want your button to change places using the float values, your div need to have a value where, when there is no space, the button goes down, put your input to be 100% the div size, and set the div to a value that you like, with .

```
*.login-container{
  width:300px;
  height:350px;
}

button{
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-top:1rem;
}
```

another thing is, I would recommend for you to learn grid-layout and flex-box.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of web development. Below are the minimal changes I made to your code to get the desired output.

```
<div class="login-container" style="">
    <h1 style="padding-bottom: 10px;">Username</h1>
    <input type="text" name="username" style="color: black; height: 50px; font-size:14pt;">
    <h1>Password</h1>
    <input type="password" name="password" style="color: black; height: 50px; font-size:14pt; margin-top: 5%;">
    <div class="login-actions">
        <center>
            <a>forgot password?</a> &nbsp;&nbsp; <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </center>
    </div>
</div>
```

I encourage you to go through modern [css frameworks](https://geekflare.com/best-css-frameworks/) that will make your life easy.

Comment: This is invalid `HTML`. I would argue this is not a minimally functional `form`. In fact, it's not even a `form`.

Answer (score 0):

Leverage `fieldset` and `label` when dealing with forms which then allows you to style them as needed using CSS.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
<fieldset>
<label for="username">User Name</label>
<input type="text" name="username" value="" maxlength="255" required="required" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<label for="password">Password</label>
<input type="password" name="password" value="" maxlength="255" required="required" /></fieldset>
<fieldset>
<button style="width: 150px;" type="submit" name="doSomething">Log In</button>
<br />
<button style="width: 150px;" type="submit" name="resetPassword">Reset Password</button>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

create a new file and test it i made it responsive now you just have to target .login-container to postion top or bottom and the font size if you want to change you can also use vw for responsive font

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: white;
}
body {
    background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/09/23/18/30/drop-3698073_960_720.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.navbar {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: darkgrey;
    height: 46px;
    border-bottom: 0.05px solid black;
}
li {
    float: left;
}
li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #a0a0a0;
    border-bottom: 0.05px solid black;
    border: 0.05px solid black;
    box-shadow: 0 12px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24), 0 17px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}
/*The body in the center of website */
.body-container {
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  
}
.menu {
    
    width: auto;
    height: 100rem;
    background-color: darkgrey;
    text-decoration-color: black;
}
.body-container .body-text {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 2.5%;
    text-align: left;
}
.body-text {
    font-size: 25px;
}

.announcement-text {
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.announcement {
    height: 100px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: auto;
    background-color: midnightblue;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

.login-container {
    top: 10%;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<body>


<?php include '../header.html'; ?>

    <div class="body-container">
        <div class="menu">
            <div class="login-container" style="">
                <h1 style="padding-bottom: 10px;">Username</h1>
                <input type="username" style="color: black; height: 50px; " name="user">
                <h1>Password</h1>
                <input type="Password" style="color: black; height: 50px; " name="user">
                <div class="button">
                <button>test</button>
            </div>
            </div>
           

        </div>
    </div>



</body>
```

Comment: i hope thats what you want